# slideDown/slideUp in IE8 with hidden elements in child containers

Tags: javascript, height, hidden, offset, slidedown

So I've got a side menu with various levels of drop down. Each level's container is set to display:none; and javascript then slides these containers up or down when clicking the parent box.

When I'm opening each block, it does not expand the parent div, and the menu slides down over the footer. Now I know what you're thinking, but I **have** tried the fix of expanding the parent element by the same height, which i have successfully used in other areas of my site.

The problem is, when I'm calculating the height of the parent div, it is coming back with the height of every single div inside added together even though they are display:none; meaning when I expand a section in the side menu, the footer drops to over 10,000px! (using parent height = parent height + expanded section height)

I've tried getting the offset.top of the footer menu and this still comes back with over 10,000px. Alerting in other browsers just returns what I would expect it to be, and I'm not massively clever with javascript to know exactly why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Example Code -

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="level1">
        <div class="level2">
            <div class="level3">
                <div class="level4">
                    SOME PRODUCTS....
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="level3">
                SOME PRODUCTS....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
            <div class="level3">
                SOME PRODUCTS....
            </div>
            <div class="level3">
                SOME PRODUCTS....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are about 850 products in the real list however. Clicking each div expands it's contents, all the way down to the product level. Some are 3 deep, while some are 5 or 6 deep. All divs are set to display:none; originally, unless a product is currently being viewed, in which case the parent divs are automatically open. It seems that IE8 reads the height of each div even though they are set to display:none;?

Comment: Can we have some code please? Actual code speaks a thousand more words!

Comment: Sure, added an example, I just didn't want to make it too long winded!